# windows server 2008 R2 licensing

Tags: windows-server-2008, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Hey, Quick question which I've be unable to find an answer to for some reason. Will Windows server 2008 license keys work with server 2008 R2?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't have to buy new CAL's for R2 but you will have to buy R2 itself. A Server 2008 License key will not activate an instance of R2.

Comment: This is correct!

Answer (score 0):

no server 2008 R2 is a different product just like 2003 r2 was a different product than 2003

Comment: "just like 2003 r2 was a different product than 2003 r2"

... what?  I think you have a spurious "R2" in there :)